# Reference on Path Analysis

Tags: references, path-model

This is not basically a research question rather an ask for help to provide me with some useful references on Path Analysis. This seems to be a trendy technique, but looks a little bit complicated. Is there any downloadable complete free book or PDF where I can find details on its theory and usage?

I need to learn the technique for mixed type of variables. Which is the easiest software for performing path analysis? I have heard about AMOS. Can't we do it in SPSS? I would also like to have suggested some references where I can learn how to use the referred software for path analysis with mixed types of variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not free, but this introduction is a great value at $16:  James Davis' *The Logic of Causal Order* (Sage pubs.)  [See reviews.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0803925530)

Comment: Thank you I have downloaded it. If I have all nominal, ordinal, binary and scale variables for a path analysis, then which software is the best?

Comment: I think a lot of people skip path analysis per se and jump to the more comprehensive (and demanding) structural equation modeling, e.g., using AMOS.  Can't help with your question about nominal variables, etc., but at 1st glance some interesting sources on path analysis in SPSS Base are http://psych.unl.edu/psycrs/942/q2/pathex1.pdf and  http://cw.psypress.com/multivariate-analysis/medical-examples/chapter07/med_path_regression.pdf .