# Mathematical details in the definition of a Structural Causal Model

Tags: model, causality, graphical-model

Pearl defines (see *Causality*, Judea Pearl, 2nd ed., Definition 7.1.1) a **Structural Causal Model** (SCM) as a triple $(\mathscr U, \mathscr V, F)$ where $\mathscr U$ is a set of "exogenous variables," $\mathscr V = \{V_1, V_2, \dots, V_n\}$ is a finite, indexed set of "endogenous variables," and $F = \{f_1, f_2, \dots, f_n\}$ is a finite, indexed set of corresponding functions such that for each $f_i\in F$, there exists a set $\mathscr U_i\subseteq \mathscr U$ and a set $\mathscr{PA}_i\subseteq \mathscr V\setminus \{V_i\}$ such that "each $f_i$ is a mapping from (the respective domains of) $\mathscr U_i\cup \mathscr {PA}_i$ to $V_i$" and "the entire set $F$ forms a mapping from $\mathscr U$ to $\mathscr V$."

I've embellished the notation relative to Pearl's with calligraphic letters to help me get straight which symbols are *sets* containing "variables" and which symbols are "variables."

I've put quotes around words that I'm hoping to get some clarification on, and those also happen to be quotations directly from the definition in Pearl's book:

1. Regarding the terms "exogenous variables" and "endogenous variables," it's not the words "exogenous" and "endogenous" that I'm worried about as these are just terms for the variables in the two sets $\mathscr U$ and $\mathscr V$.  I'd instead like to know precisely what sorts of mathematical objects the "variables" are.  At first I thought that maybe they were random variables on a probability space, but it seems that Pearl wants to distinguish between a "structural causal model" and a "probabilistic structural causal model," so now I'm thinking that these variables are simply functions from a set of outcomes $\Omega$ (possibly different for each variable) to some set/space of values, and that there need not be any probability measure to speak of.  Wether or not this is true, this leads to my next question:
2. If it's true that each "variable" is a function from some set of outcomes to a set/space of values, then can each of these variables have a different outcome set as its domain?  Based on the wording of the rest of the definition, I'm guessing that the answer is "yes," but since the model is supposed to describe a single data generating process with some set of possible outcomes, I *feel* like the appropriate thing would be for all variables to share the same outcome set/space as their common domain.  If the outcome sets are allowed to be different, what's the motivation for this degree of generality in the definition in terms of modeling real systems?
3. When Pearl says "each $f_i$ is a mapping from (the respective domains of) $\mathscr U_i\cup \mathscr{PA}_i$ to $V_i$," and "the entire set $F$ forms a mapping from $U$ to $V$," my interpretation of this given his use of other notation in the book is that the domain of each function $f_i$ is the cartesian product of the domains of the variables in $\mathscr U_i$ and the variables in $\mathscr{PA}_i$, while the codomain for $f_i$ is the codomain of the variable $V_i$.  To be concrete, I'm imagining that if 
   $$\mathscr U_i = \{U_{i,1},U_{i,2}, U_{i,3}\}$$ 
   and
   $$\mathscr{PA}_i = \{V_{i,1}, V_{i,2}\},$$ then 
   $$f_i: \mathrm{dom}(U_{i,1})\times \mathrm{dom}(U_{i,2})\times\mathrm{dom}(U_{i,3})\times \mathrm{dom}(V_{i,1})\times\mathrm{dom}(V_{i,2})\to \mathrm{codomain}(V_i)$$
   where $\mathrm{dom}$ denotes the domain of a function and $\mathrm{codomain}$ denotes the codomain of a function.  Is this correct?

**Edit. January 20, 2020**

I think I misinterpreted the phrase "respective domains of" in Pearl's definition.  I think what Pearl means is that a variable on a set of outcomes partitions that set according to its values (outcomes with the same value assigned to them fall in the same partition), and that the functions in the SCM are strictly-speaking taking in the *values* of the variables as their arguments, not elements of their domains.

What follows is what I now perceive to be the intended definition of an SCM.  In particular, I think the variables in the model are intended to share an outcome set, or at least it's not hard to accommodate that within a definition and preserve its spirit.

1. Let $\Omega$ be a set.  We call elements of $\Omega$ **outcomes**.
2. A **variable** on the set $\Omega$ is a function whose domain is $\Omega$.  Let $R(V)$ denote the range of any variable $V$ on $\Omega$.
3. Let $\mathscr U = \{U_1, U_2, \dots, U_m\}$ be a finite set of variables on $\Omega$ which we call **exogenous**.
4. Let $\mathscr V = \{V_1, V_2, \dots, V_n\}$ be a finite set of variables on $\Omega$ which we call **endogenous**.
5. Suppose that $V_i\in \mathscr V$, let $\mathscr{PA}_i\subseteq\mathscr V\setminus \{V_i\} = \{V_{i_1}, \dots V_{i_k}\}$, and let $\mathscr U_i\subseteq\mathscr U = \{U_{i_1}, \dots, U_{i_\ell}\}$.  A function
   $$
     f_i: R(V_{i_1})\times\cdots\times R(V_{i_k})\times R(U_{i_1})\times \cdots \times R(U_{i_\ell}) \to V_i
   $$
   is called a **structural function** relative to the triple $(V_i, \mathscr U_i, \mathscr{PA}_i)$.
6. Let $F = \{f_1, f_2, \dots, f_n\}$ be a set of functions such that each $f_i$ is a structural function relative to some triple $(V_i, \mathscr U_i, \mathscr{PA}_i)$.
7. The triple $(\mathscr U, \mathscr V, F)$ is called a **Structural Causal Model** over $\Omega$.