# Does $y=f(x)$ implies $X$ Granger-causes $Y$?

Tags: granger-causality

Factor in the information from the question ["Does causation imply correlation?"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26300/does-causation-imply-correlation), ["Mathematical Definition of Causality"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69806/mathematical-definition-of-causality), and ["How to formally tell is one time series affects another"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/73085/how-to-formally-tell-if-one-time-series-affects-another).

Let $y = f(x)$, where $f$ is continuous and differentiable. Does this guarantee that $x$ will Granger-cause $y$?

Given that $f$ can be horribly nonlinear, it seems that there are a limited number of tests and methods for conditioning the data in such a way that the granger causality test can be applied effectively. Even something like $y=e^x + \epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ is white noise, can cause problems with estimating the order of integration (thus testing for cointegration, and then Granger-causality according to the Toda and Yamamoto method as described in Dave Giles' [blog post](https://davegiles.blogspot.com/2011/04/testing-for-granger-causality.html)).

Comment: Could you clarify the sense in which a function $f$ could be considered as related to Granger causality, which concerns predictability in a time series?

Comment: See also my comment under the answer.

Comment: @whuber - Take the equation for force, mass, and acceleration F = ma, where mass is constant. I'm under the impression that if F = ma, then F should granger-cause a (because it actually causes a). Is that misguided?

Comment: @whuber - Thinking about this harder, I will post a separate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Consider $x(t) \sim \operatorname{Uniform}(-1,1)$. For any function $f$, including $f(x)=x$ and $f(x)=0$ it is obvious to see that past values of $x$ don't help in predicting $y$.

Comment: Granger causality requires past values of $x$ to help in predicting $y$ *once the predictive information contained in past values of $y$ has been accounted for*. Forgetting the latter clause seems to be a common mistake.

Comment: @RichardHardy - I'll replace my previous question with this one: doesn't that imply that for test for Granger-Causality, y must be a function of at least 2 variables with (each with their own auto-regressions)?