# Generate Variables from Causal Structure for Simulation with Binary/Indicators

Tags: correlation, simulation, causality

I would like to generate a data set of variables from a specific causal structural (a stylized world) for simulation, [similar to this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/312646/simulating-data-correlation-vs-causation), but most of the key variables are binary/indicators.

Specifically, my example wants to capture the relationship between example variables surgery, clinical variables, and patient race from the following structural model:

[image: ![enter image description here]

I will then use the created data to demonstrate confounding applied to this setting. However, each variable, except 'appropriate', is an indicator variable i.e. 1 if the true and 0 if false, which makes setting up the systems of equations tricky to make into simple linear combinations.

How should I create these equations?

To show an attempt in R, I tried to create the structural equations for this stylized world as such:

```
Black <- rbinom(reps, 1, .5)
U <- rnorm(reps)
Appropriate <- (1/(1+exp(-U)))
ST_Elev <- as.numeric(2*Black + 3*Appropriate + rnorm(reps) > 2)
LowSES <- as.numeric(3*Black+rnorm(reps)>2.5)
Surgery <- as.numeric(5*Appropriate+LowSES+2*ST_Elev+rnorm(reps) > 3.5)

world <- data.frame(Black ,
                    ST_Elev,
                    LowSES,
                    Appropriate,
                    Surgery)
```

by just creating indicators with the right proportions based on being greater than some value. But this formation doesn't nicely follow with my (limited) understanding of structural causal models and I can't figure out how to control the relationships as well directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How should I create these equations?

There is no single right way to simulate the equations: any parametric form you choose for the structural equations is a valid model, as long as they satisfy the assumptions encoded in the DAG: exclusions restrictions of what is a direct cause of what, and independence restrictions of which error terms are independent. In fact, your approach is fine, you are simulating the structural equations with the [latent variable representation of probits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probit_model).

> and I can't figure out how to control the relationships as well
>   directly

Since all variables are binary, you can also easily simulate a linear probability model or a logit.   Here I will show an example using a linear probability model, maybe it will be easier for you to control exactly the conditional probabilities you want in the simulation:

```
reps <- 1e3
Black <- rbinom(reps, 1, .5)
Appropriate <- rbinom(reps, 1, .5)
ST_Elev <- rbinom(reps, 1, .1 + .1*Black + .2*Appropriate)
LowSES <- rbinom(reps, 1, .15+ .3*Black)
Surgery <- rbinom(reps, 1, .2*Appropriate + .1*LowSES + .2*ST_Elev)
```